# how can i click on another element, when original was not found?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, try-catch

I've created a function to select the payment randomly (number). when the first selection (number) is not found (try catch) then I want to select another one.

But I always receive:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'click'

when sending number 8 and it should select credit cart visa...

What am i doing wrong? The elements are really there and the id is also correct:

```
CheckoutPage3.prototype.selectPayment = function (number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        try {
            this.elementPaymentPaypal.click().then(function () {
                return 1;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("payment not found, select new");
                this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
                this.elementCreditVISA.click();
                number = 2;
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('error occured');
        }
    }
    else if (number == 2) {
        this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
        this.elementCreditVISA.click();
        number = 2;
    } else if (number == 3) {
        this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
        this.elementCreditMasterCard.click();
        number = 3;
    }
    else if (number == 4) {
        try {
            this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
            this.elementCreditAmericanExpress.click().then(function () {
                number = 4;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("payment not found, select new");
                this.elementCreditVISA.click();
                number = 2;
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('error occured');
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            this.elementPrePayment.click().then(function () {
                number = 5;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("payment not found, select new");
                this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
                this.elementCreditVISA.click();
                number = 2;
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('error occured');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [common problem in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), in your page object the *`this` is not always something you expect it to be*. For example, in the promise resolution function here:

```
this.elementPaymentPaypal.click().then(function () {
    return 1;
}, function (err) {
    console.log("payment not found, select new");
    this.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();  // < HERE
    this.elementCreditVISA.click();  // < and HERE
    number = 2;
});
```

`this` does not refer to the instance of the "current" page object anymore.

The common way to approach the problem is to save the reference to `this` in the parent scope:

```
CheckoutPage3.prototype.selectPayment = function (number) {
    var self = this;

    if (number == 1) {
        try {
            // ...
```

And then use `self` instead of `this`:

```
this.elementPaymentPaypal.click().then(function () {
    return 1;
}, function (err) {
    console.log("payment not found, select new");
    self.elementPaymentCreditCard.click();
    self.elementCreditVISA.click();
    number = 2;
});
```